# youtube video file direct downloading / downloading blocked videos

Tags: audio, video, youtube

for example, here is a video that is blocked in every country:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QUOzJt8H3Y4

how come this site:https://www.youtube2mp3.cc/ can get/download its audio track in mp3, but cant get/download the video in mp4? whats the difference?

youtube-mp3.org can also get its audio

also tried youtube-dl but didnt work (only tried the plain command)

is there any way to get the video when its blocked, not just the audio? i guessed the audio and video werent separated, but this shows otherwise

EDIT:tried youtube-dl with the --get-url option too, returned the same error youtube does in the browser

Comment: So, you ckecked for every country that this video is blocked? How Did you do that?

Comment: no, i searched for "regionsAllowed" in the html of the page. i was wrong though, its not blocked in every country. my browser displayed it wrong i guess, it listed the countries from A to Z, as if those were what were in fact blocked, not allowed. now this browser displays what are actually allowed, and they are: "BL,GG,GS,IM,JE,ME,MF,PS,SS"

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can view or download a globally blocked video. The MP3 sites probably have the audio cached from a previous request, before it was blocked.

Comment: i doubt it though. you can try with the videos here for example: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL65DB5C35359533A1
i didnt try it with any of them. the youtube2mp3 site also says this in the "Service" menu item: In opposition to other website you are able to download videos which are not available or blocked in your country - please note, you can only download videos which haven't been deleted.

Comment: and sorry for the late reply

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of possible answers - the first is that this was cached by the site prior to it being deleted - and indeed, when I tried it it was available immediately which would imply to me that is most probably the case - as I'd expect downloading and converting it to MP3 to take a noticeable amount of time.

From some researching, I believe that the video has not been "blocked in every country", but rather has been blocked in most places. Googling [here](http://www.proxynova.com/proxy-articles/watch-youtube-videos-blocked-in-your-country/) showed that this video is not blocked in Sudan !!!  It is conceivable that the player downloaded it through a proxy in Sudan (or may from an IP not in a GEOIP list).

Comment: i doubt it was cached, but the site also claims to be able to download blocked videos, under the "Service" menu. https://www.youtube2mp3.cc/service/
i was probably wrong about it being blocked everywhere though. i checked the "regionsAllowed" metatag, or what it is, on the youtube page. on my other browser, it listed all the countries from A to Z, or at least i thought so, so i thought it works the opposite way than on this browser, where it only has these:"BL,GG,GS,IM,JE,ME,MF,PS,SS" SS probably means south sudan, but then the other regions should be allowed too. and sorry for the late reply.